# Faults in a RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, fault

Suppose we have a classic RLC circuit, in series and with constant voltage.
Let's suppose that the resistance, the inductance and the capacitance can be affected by a fault.

- For which components can I discover the fault using a static (steady) model (analysis) of the circuit?
- And for which components do I have to use a dynamic model (analysis) of the circuit to discover the fault?

*EDIT:*

My deduction are:

1. If the resistance doesn't work ( short ) it sufficient to check the voltage 
    across the capacitor after the transient is ended. If is 0 then the 
    resistance is short. The same apply to check if the inductance either 
    capacitance are shorted.
2. In order to know if a fault altered the values of R,L or C i have to check the transient response.

Is it correct ?

Comment: Even though the circuit is "obvious" just include it for completeness, there's a circuit editor available when you edit your question. Then explain what you mean by "a fault". Fail short and/or open and/or wrong value? Also you need to do a bit of preparation / thinking. What would be (an example of) a static test? And a dynamic test. What happens when all components are OK? What if the capacitor has failed short? Go through all possible cases.

Comment: Since i don't know where to start, do you know some book/material about it ?

Comment: Almost all books about electronics teach the basics needed to understand this.

Comment: This is homework. Tell us how far you've got.

Comment: I added my deductions. Are correct ?

Comment: Do you think we are mind readers? Draw the circuit out and tell us what you mean by fault. An classic RLC circuit can mean anything. Are they all in parralel? Are they a filter configuration? If you want an awnser on this website, give it to us on a silver spoon. And FYI if you simply googled RLC circuit on Google there is more than enough information.